# Visual Studio 2017 Build tools issue with enum type

Tags: c++, visual-studio, enums

I have the very simply code:

```
typedef long int32;
typedef unsigned long uint32;

enum Foo : int32 {
  kE1 = 100
};

bool f(int32 i) {
  return true;
}

bool f(uint32 i) {
  return false;
}

int main()
{
  int32 i32 = 8;
  uint32 ui32 = 10;

  f(i32);
  f(ui32);

  f(Foo::kE1);

  return 0;
}
```

When compiling with Visual Studio Build tools 2017, I am getting an error:

```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\CL.exe /c /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:classic /Od /Ob0 /Oy- /D WIN32
   /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /GR /std:c++17 /Fo"cpp17.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cpp17.dir\Deb
  ug\vc141.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /FC /errorReport:queue D:\Work\test\cpp17\main.cpp
  main.cpp
d:\work\test\cpp17\main.cpp(24): error C2668: 'f': ambiguous call to overloaded function [D:\Work\test\cpp17\build\cpp17.vcxproj]
  d:\work\test\cpp17\main.cpp(12): note: could be 'bool f(uint32)'
  d:\work\test\cpp17\main.cpp(8): note: or       'bool f(int32)'
  d:\work\test\cpp17\main.cpp(24): note: while trying to match the argument list '(Foo)'
Done Building Project "D:\Work\test\cpp17\build\cpp17.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
```

I don't understand what it is an ambiguous call. The enum is clearly marked as being of type `int32` (`enum Foo : int32`).

I do not have this issue on macOS with XCode.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this is an issue with Visual Studio build tools?

Comment: The easy workaround is simply to invoke f with the enum type as `f((int32)Foo::kE1);`  Does that work?

Comment: works in visual studio 2019 update 1 or later, update to the latest version of visual studio https://godbolt.org/z/CbqpJK

Comment: I'll admit I'm not entirely familiar with what the standards say, but it does seem like an issue with VS2017. Your code (copy and pasted) works fine in VS2019.

Comment: @yan It is a compiler bug. Check whether the option"language extensions" of the compiler is on.

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestions in the comments, I upgraded to Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 and I confirm that it does indeed fix the issue.

As a side note, I discovered that installing Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 somehow does not work with older version of cmake which was installed on my system. To fix this other issue, I uninstalled `CMake` and added `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin` to the Path.